# Apache mod_rewrite: force HTTPS in one subdomain and force HTTP for another

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https

I have this code, but not works well:
I want omly HTTP to a-subdomain and only HTTPS to subdomain....

**Edited with the changed code based on @Dusan Bajic:**

```
#Trying to force https, this works...
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^a-subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

#Trying to force http, not works...
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a-subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

> subdomain redirects to HTTPS - it is Ok.
>
> a-subdomain can be accessed via HTTP - it is ok
>
> a-subdomain continues accessed via HTTPS - it is **not** ok.

Comment: Is your <VirtualHost *:443> configured with `AllowOverride All`?

Comment: Is a webhost with cpanel, how known is this option is set? Asking the support?

Comment: Can you , just as a quick test, add `RewriteRule ^ - [F]` as a last line, and check if it breaks https site

Comment: With this line at end of all, if access the a-subdomain with https give me the same error (incorrect redirect), if access with HTTP, give me 403. Without this line, the HTTP works...

Comment: Is all the above code in .htaccess or in apache .conf file?

Comment: In HTACCESS, this is the complete HTACCESS: https://pastebin.com/Yhs4dzVX

Comment: Do you have access to apache .conf files?

Comment: No, it is webserver with cpanel, my account is a host account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) syntax:

```
RewriteCond TestString CondPattern [flags]
```

`CondPattern` (when used without any prefix) is a perl compatible regular expression. 
When prefixed with `=`, `CondPattern` as treated as a plain string and compared lexicographically to `TestString`

Use either:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =a-subdomain.domain.com
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a-subdomain\.domain\.com$
```

Comment: Thks :) I changed the first cond to this: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^a-subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]`  and the second cond to this `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a-subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]`, better, but not works 100%. if the a-subdomain is access with HTTP, it works, but if is access with HTTPS, it continues with HTTPS.

Comment: can you please try one more thing: what is the response from `curl -v https://a-subdomain.domain.com`

Comment: The curl returned this log: https://pastebin.com/xEphfhdf  -- seems to be working, the apache redirect to the version HTTP, but, in chrome have a redirect loop, others browser do not work ... strange...

Comment: Wait a minute: if you try `https://a-subdomain.domain.com` in chrome, does it open the site with https, or results in redirect loop?

Comment: Aaah, remove `Strict-Transport-Security` from .htaccess and test from a clean browser :)